# ¿Como puedo darle la señal de audio de mi computadora a python para efectuar cambios en dicha señal y luego reproducirla?

Tags: python

mi objetivo final es armar un ecualizador para hacerlo tengo dos opciones: que sea un software de pc y se haga todo dentro de este o retirar la señal de audio del pc y pasarla a un rasperry pi para que el codigo corra de manera externa. Como yo lo veo el problema con esto es que no se como darle la señal que se esta reproduciendo a python para poder hacerle las modificaciones que uno desee. Por otro lado si tienen datos de librerias que serian utiles para la resolucion de este problema seria grandioso si podrian hacermelos llegar.

Answer (score -1):

[Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) y [Portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) son librerías en C/C++ que te pueden ayudar con tu objetivo.

Como se describe en su sitio, Jack es un servidor de audio que te permite:

- Pasar la salida de audio de un programa a otro
- Grabar la señal de audio proveniente de otro programa
- Compartir dispositivos y enrutamiento de audio entre aplicaciones

Por su parte, Portaudio es el backend hardware, que te permite acceder a los dispositivos, grabar y reproducir. Ambos son proyectos Open Source.

También hay unas implementaciones en Python, PyJack y PyAudio.

Comment: responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad; toda vez que si los sitios enlazados dejan de funcionar la información se pierde; dale editar y añade una explicación mas completa asi como ejemplos de cada uno

Comment: Una respuesta que contiene solamente un enlace a la solución corre el riesgo de que el sitio enlazado desaparezca y se pierda su valor. Es preferible que pongas en la respuesta la información esencial para resolver el problema planteado y puedes dejar el enlace como una referencia externa que amplía el tema. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).